# SQL Training Exercise Assistance

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can anyone please help me tweak these queries. I am working through some training examples and can't seem to nail these ones;

The first one is to return the title and sub title of books that have no copies in the library and write the query using a EXISTS/NOT EXISTS. So I have this (might not be the best);

```
SELECT title, subtitle
FROM book
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT bookid, bookdescid, count(*)
  FROM book_copy
  GROUP BY bookdescid
  HAVING count(*) = 1);
```

But then I am struggling with writing the next two variations;

1. Write the query again using a JOIN (but not using a RIGHT or FULL
   OUTER JOIN)
2. Write the query again using SET operators

Here are the table structures;

[book table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgNI.png)

[book_copy table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2btJ.png)

Many books have different BOOKDESCID but have the same name. And BOOKDESCID in book_copy is the way to identify different copies of the same book

Using sqlite studio

Many thanks

Comment: And what is a library in your tables? Sample data, current and desired results would help others understanding your question.

Comment: @KJDD1: English is not my native language, but I still think you have misunderstood the task. Yes, a copy *can* mean a copy of an original. Then having "no copy in the library" would mean that there is only the original book and no copy of it in the library. But I find this unlikely. It is much more likely that all books in the library are "copies". The task is hence to find books that are not in the library (something like `select * from book b where not exists (select null from book_copy bc where bc.bookdescid = b.bookdescid)`).

Comment: On a side note: The database would be easier to understand with consistent names. The primary key in the book table should be called book_id and the primary key in the book_copy table should be called book_copy_id. That bookid is not the book pk, but the book_copy pk is confusing.

Comment: @KJDD1 Don't vandalize your question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED POST-ACLARATION:**

First one, with exists:

```
SELECT title, subtitle
FROM book b
where exists (select bc.bookid, count(*)
                from book_copy bc 
                where bc.bookdescid = b.bookdescid
                group by bc.bookid
                having count(*) = 1);
```

Second with INNER JOIN:

```
 select b.bookid, count(*)
 FROM book b
    inner join book_copy bc on bc.bookdescid = b.bookdescid
 group by b.bookid
 having count(*) = 1;
```

if you need title and subtitle columns in the selected columns you could use an in:

```
 select title, subtitle
 from book
 where bookid in (select b.bookid
       FROM book b
          inner join book_copy bc on bc.bookdescid = b.bookdescid
       group by b.bookid
       having count(*) = 1)
```

And  the final one with set operators:

```
SELECT b.bookid, 
FROM book b
EXCEPT
select b.bookid
       FROM book b
          inner join book_copy bc on bc.bookdescid = b.bookdescid
       group by b.bookid
       having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: "So the question is to return the title and sub title of books that have no copies" you mean titles, that dont have more than one bookid in book_copy table (by bookdescid)?